# Hover dependant behavior of two elements : when A or B are hovered show A

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

here is my CodePen **[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENmWmB)** or you can **run the snippet** below.

In the original script, the front face of the cube is a slider, and when I hover my 'info-box' it shows the right side of it with some description (`<p>` an `<a>`).

The expected behavior is that **as long as the user stays on the description, the element keeps having the `.hover` class given in the `$('#info-box').hover()` function**

All was working fine until i tested it on chrome :(...

From what I understand, it seems to fires multiples `mouseOver/mouseOut` events when hovering and it messes and flicker everything up.

Should I use a `setTimeout` ?

```js
$('.slide-info').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
  })
  .hover(function() {
      $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
    });

$('.right').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('hover');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('hover');
  });
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.Cube-container {
  width: 500px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -250px;
}
.Cube {
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.front,
.right {
  height: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.Cube-container.hover .Cube {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -250px;
}
.front {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  background-color: #fc8;
  position: relative;
}
.right {
  background-color: #8cf;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  /* because it takes in account the padding, i guess we can do some box-sizing: border box to avoid that...*/
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.ol
/* OverLay */

{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide-info {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Cube-container">
  <div class="ol Cube">
    <div class="ol right">
      <h2>Right side</h2>
      <p>While we hover that side, parent element keeps having the .hover class, making it visible</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ol front">
      <h2>Front</h2>
      <p>Hover the info box please :)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ol slide-info">
    <h3>INFO</h3>
  </div>
</div>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Comment: Looks fine, what is the problem?

Comment: Fine on Chrome for me as well

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used `backface-visibility: hidden` on parent element. (see commented line in snippet)

Crazy but that solved my problem on Chrome browser, now everything works fine.

```js
$('.slide-info').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
  })
  .hover(function() {
      $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
    });

$('.right').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('hover');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('hover');
  });
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.Cube-container {
  width: 500px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -250px;
}
.Cube {
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /*backface-visibility:hidden; <-- Causing the problem */ 
}
.front,
.right {
  height: 150%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.Cube-container.hover .Cube {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -250px;
}
.front {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  background-color: #fc8;
  position: relative;
}
.right {
  background-color: #8cf;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  /* because it takes in account the padding, i guess we can do some box-sizing: border box to avoid that...*/
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.ol
/* OverLay */

{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide-info {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Cube-container">
  <div class="ol Cube">
    <div class="ol right">
      <h2>Right side</h2>
      <p>While we hover that side, parent element keeps having the .hover class, making it visible</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ol front">
      <h2>Front</h2>
      <p>Hover the info box please :)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ol slide-info">
    <h3>INFO</h3>
  </div>
</div>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```